# How to use jPlayer with Wavesurfer-JS as audio player?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, jplayer, waveform

I'm using [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/) as audio player for my music library and [Wavesurfer-JS](http://wavesurfer-js.org/) for draw my waveforms.

Waveforms are generated by using JSON data like this (long code in the snippet):

```
wavesurfer.backend.peaks = [...];
wavesurfer.drawBuffer();
```

**Eg.** This is my audio player so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


  var playlist = [{
      title:"Hidden",
      artist:"Miaow",
      mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-02-Hidden.mp3",
      oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-02-Hidden.ogg",
      poster: "https://i.imgur.com/sCbrzQa.png"
    },{
      title:"Cro Magnon Man",
      artist:"The Stark Palace",
      mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3",
      oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.ogg",
      poster: "https://i.imgur.com/lXvsuBu.png"
    },{
      title:"Bubble",
      m4a: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a",
      oga: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg",
      poster: "https://i.imgur.com/klJKSVZ.jpg"
  }];
  
  var cssSelector = {
    jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer",
    cssSelectorAncestor: ".music-player"
  };
  
  var options = {
    swfPath: "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jplayer/2.6.4/jquery.jplayer/Jplayer.swf",
    supplied: "ogv, m4v, oga, mp3",
    volumechange: function(event) {
      $( ".volume-level" ).slider("value", event.jPlayer.options.volume);
    },
    timeupdate: function(event) {
      $( ".progress" ).slider("value", event.jPlayer.status.currentPercentAbsolute);
    }
  };
  
  var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist(cssSelector, playlist, options);
  var PlayerData = $(cssSelector.jPlayer).data("jPlayer");
  
  
  // Create the volume slider control
  $( ".volume-level" ).slider({
     animate: "fast",
  max: 1,
  range: "min",
  step: 0.01,
  value : $.jPlayer.prototype.options.volume,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
   $(cssSelector.jPlayer).jPlayer("option", "muted", false);
   $(cssSelector.jPlayer).jPlayer("option", "volume", ui.value);
  }
  });
  
  // Create the progress slider control
  $( ".progress" ).slider({
  animate: "fast",
  max: 100,
  range: "min",
  step: 0.1,
  value : 0,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
   var sp = PlayerData.status.seekPercent;
   if(sp > 0) {
    // Move the play-head to the value and factor in the seek percent.
    $(cssSelector.jPlayer).jPlayer("playHead", ui.value * (100 / sp));
   } else {
    // Create a timeout to reset this slider to zero.
    setTimeout(function() {
      $( ".progress" ).slider("value", 0);
    }, 0);
   }
  }
 });

  
});
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.music-player {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 370px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}
.music-player img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
          filter: blur(2px);
}
.music-player .info {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background: #222;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.music-player .info .jp-playlist li {
  display: none;
}
.music-player .info .jp-playlist li a {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.4);
}
.music-player .info .jp-playlist li a span {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.music-player .info .jp-playlist li.jp-playlist-current {
  display: block;
}
.music-player .info .jp-playlist li .jp-free-media, .music-player .info .jp-playlist li .jp-playlist-item-remove {
  display: none;
}
.music-player .info .left, .music-player .info .right {
  width: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
}
.music-player .info .right {
  left: auto;
  right: 30px;
}
.music-player .info [class^="icon-"] {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.music-player .info .center {
  padding: 6px 0 0;
}
.music-player .progress, .music-player .volume-level {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}
.music-player .progress .ui-slider-range, .music-player .volume-level .ui-slider-range {
  display: block;
  background: #ed553b;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.music-player .progress .ui-slider-handle, .music-player .volume-level .ui-slider-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 22px;
  background: url("//i.imgur.com/tsqwz1N.png") no-repeat center;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 -3px;
  cursor: move;
}
.music-player .controls {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 190px;
  background: #982e4b;
  background: rgba(152, 46, 75, 0.6);
}
.music-player .controls .current {
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #fff;
  color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.4);
  padding: 15px 0 20px;
}
.music-player .controls .play-controls a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 30px;
}
.music-player .controls .volume-level {
  position: relative;
  bottom: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  background: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.3);
}
.music-player .controls .volume-level .ui-slider-range {
  height: 2px;
}
.music-player .controls .volume-level .ui-slider-handle {
  top: -8px;
  margin-left: -9px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/106/106874.svg");
}
.music-player .controls .volume-level .icon-volume-up, .music-player .controls .volume-level .icon-volume-down {
  position: absolute;
  right: -34px;
  top: -8px;
  width: 22px;
}
.music-player .controls .volume-level .icon-volume-down {
  right: auto;
  left: -27px;
}

[class^="icon-"] {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background: url("//i.imgur.com/E09T8tf.png") no-repeat center;
  display: block;
}

.icon-shuffle {
  background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/148/148739.svg");
}
.icon-heart {
  background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/138/138533.svg");
}
.icon-repeat {
  background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/137/137485.svg");
}
.icon-share {
  background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/189/189676.svg");
}
.icon-previous {
  background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/137/137518.svg");
}
.icon-play {
  background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/148/148744.svg");
}
.icon-pause {
  background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/189/189639.svg");
}
.icon-next {
  background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/137/137517.svg");
}
.icon-volume-up {
  background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149139.svg");
}
.icon-volume-down {
  background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/109/109699.svg");
}
ul, menu, dir {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.0.52/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jplayer/2.6.4/jquery.jplayer/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jplayer/2.6.4/add-on/jplayer.playlist.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="music-player">
  <div style="background-image: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/welcome-summer-badge-on-blurry-background_23-2147511412.jpg);" class="album"></div>

  <div class="info">  
    <div class="left">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-shuffle"></a>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-heart"></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="center">
      <div class="jp-playlist">
        <ul>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="right">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-repeat"></a>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-share"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="progress"></div>  
  </div>
  
  <div class="demo">
      <div id="waveform"></div>

      <script>
        var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
        var linGrad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 64, 0, 200);
        linGrad.addColorStop(0.5, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.000)');
        linGrad.addColorStop(0.5, 'rgba(183, 183, 183, 1.000)');

        var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
          container: '#waveform',
          waveColor: linGrad,
          progressColor: 'hsla(200, 100%, 30%, 0.5)',
          cursorColor: '#fff',
          normalize: true,
          backend: 'MediaElement',
          height:50,
          barWidth: 3
        });
        //Set peaks
        wavesurfer.backend.peaks = [0.0218, 0.0183, 0.0165, 0.0198, 0.2137, 0.2888, 0.2313, 0.15, 0.2542, 0.2538, 0.2358, 0.1195, 0.1591, 0.2599, 0.2742, 0.1447, 0.2328, 0.1878, 0.1988, 0.1645, 0.1218, 0.2005, 0.2828, 0.2051, 0.1664, 0.1181, 0.1621, 0.2966, 0.189, 0.246, 0.2445, 0.1621, 0.1618, 0.189, 0.2354, 0.1561, 0.1638, 0.2799, 0.0923, 0.1659, 0.1675, 0.1268, 0.0984, 0.0997, 0.1248, 0.1495, 0.1431, 0.1236, 0.1755, 0.1183, 0.1349, 0.1018, 0.1109, 0.1833, 0.1813, 0.1422, 0.0961, 0.1191, 0.0791, 0.0631, 0.0315, 0.0157, 0.0166, 0.0108];

        //Draw peaks
        wavesurfer.drawBuffer();
      </script> 
  </div>    

  <div class="controls">
    <div class="current jp-current-time">00:00</div>
    <div class="play-controls">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-previous jp-previous" title="previous"></a>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-play jp-play" title="play"></a>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-pause jp-pause" title="pause"></a>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-next jp-next" title="next"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="volume-level">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-volume-up" title="max volume"></a>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-volume-down" title="mute"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="jquery_jplayer" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
  
</div>
```

As you can see from this snippet the progress bar works only for jPlayer.
**I want to keep the jPlayer as it is and use my waveform as progress bar.**

How can I use as progress bar my waveform without loading the song from Wavesurfer-JS but only using my pre-generated waveform with the jPlayer?

Comment: Were you able to find the solution ?

Comment: @Presse not really...I decided to don't use Wavesurfer

Comment: @Presse I had a look at the source code for wavesurfer and I don't think you can. They use different API's that conflict with each other, i.e wavesurfer isn't just a dynamic progress bar it also has methods such as `play()`, `pause()` etc. Maybe their is a way but it would be messy and ugly trying to mix them.

If you really really wanted to mix them it would probably be eaiser to rip out the wave surfer dynamic bar stuff and make an add-on for jPlayer but I don't recommend this either because jPlayer is completely dead now (not being updated).

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson yes, the latest update it's 3 years old but it works well also with jQuery 3.1 But definetely I reccomend something alternative like [Howler](https://howlerjs.com/)

Comment: Thank you @MartinMazzaDawson